# Why does Safaris Responsive Design Mode render fonts unreadable?

Tags: fonts, safari, mode

Is it just me or why does Safari 9's responsive design mode render fonts almost unreadable?

Everything is fine until I switch on the responsive design mode. See the screenshot from nytimes.com below:

Safari Responsive Design Mode font issue:

[image: Safari Responsive Design Mode font issue]

This has always been the case for me, it didn't appear just yesterday. 
I am using a **non-retina 21.5'' iMac** and **El Capitan 10.11.3**

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself. 
You can change the pixel density mode (1x, 2x, 3x) at the top. Changing this to 1x on a non-retina display makes the text render almost normally.

Comment: Not just you. Fixed for me, too (while working on a Safari-specific issue). Thanks!